# How to selectRowAtIndexPath after user cancels delete

Tags: ios, objective-c

User swipes to the left in order to delete a cell. Changes his/her mind and taps the screen in order to get out of the delete mode for that cell (or can even swipe the cell from left to right for the same effect). However, now there are no cells selected. Where do I insert selectRowAtIndexPath in order to select a row after the user cancels the deletion of a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidEndEditingRowAtIndexPath%3a) delegate method.

Per the docs:

> This method is called when the table view exits editing mode after having been put into the mode by the user swiping across the row identified by indexPath...